# Getting API key for GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, api-key

I'm trying to register my android app with GCM, I followed the instructions in [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) in order to obtain an api key, I did what is written in numbers 1-7 but in step 8 I can't find
the Android Key section.

What should I do?

p.s.
When I try to register my device with gcm `gcm.register(SENDER_ID)` I get error saying service not available, are those to problems connected? or this error is something else? (I didn't write the server part of the application)

android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appspot.smartgan"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.appspot.smartgan.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.appspot.smartgan.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.appspot.smartgan.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.appspot.smartgan" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.appspot.smartgan.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.appspot.smartgan.ChildActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_child" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

registration code: (I used the code from an example Google published)

```
private void registerInBackground() {   
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        String str = "";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String message = "";

            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                message = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                Log.d("SMARTGAN_PLAY", "register completed");

                // send registration id to the server
                sendRegistrationIdToServer();

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                message = "Error:" + e.getMessage();
            }
            str = message;
            return message;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
            childrenTextView.setText(str);
        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an API Key in order to register to GCM. You only need a Sender ID (which is the Project ID of the Google API Project you created for your app). The API Key is only needed in the server side for sending GCM messages to your app.

The reason for getting service not available can be many things. You'll have to post your manifest and client registration code to get more help.

Comment: I too have the same problem. I notice that @meda has actual integer as project id but on my side the project is identified as string "prismatic-petal-438" and I get the invalid_sender message. There are a lot of examples for depreciated c2dm but gcm not so much

Comment: Sorry just found out that you need to use Project Number as the project ID duh...

Answer (score 0):

```
//Subtitute with your own project ID
String SENDER_ID = "46086692976";
```

See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. SENDER_ID is defined and has the right value I just didn't think I was important.

Comment: well  the error suggest that the SENDERID is invalid you need to make sure its the correct one I have beentgrough that bbefore

Comment: I don't know what to do with it... I copied the project number from the cloud console (ctrl + C)

Comment: @DorMesica Paste it where you assign the value to `SENDER_ID`

Comment: That's what I did I defined `public static final String SENDER_ID="<project number copied from Google Cloud Console>"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @DorMesica then it means google play service is not available, I believe you need to have a gmail account, Im going to research that now

Comment: I followed the example code Google posted in the link I've added to the original question, it includes a code for checking whether or not Google play services is available on the device, plus I tried this application on my phone and I have both Google Play services and a Gmail account. I've googled this problem for hours with no success in finding how to fix it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43368/discussion-between-meda-and-dor-mesica)